# Substituting two different identifiers with the same identifier in Coq - why does this work?

Tags: logic, induction, coq

I'm playing around with Coq and Software Foundations and is somehow very confused by something I took for granted since forever.

To prove

```
Theorem app_length_cons : forall (X:Type) (l1:list X) (x:X),
                              length (l1 ++ x :: l1) = S (length (l1 ++ l1)).
```

we can first prove

```
Theorem app_length_cons' : forall (X:Type) (l1 l2:list X) (x:X),
                             length (l1 ++ x :: l2) = S (length (l1 ++ l2)).
```

which is a straightforward induction,

```
Proof.
  intros.
  induction l1 as [| h l1'].
  reflexivity.
  simpl.
  rewrite -> IHl1'.
  reflexivity.
Qed.
```

Then simply

```
Proof.
  intros.
  apply app_length_cons' with (l1:=l1) (l2:=l1).
Qed.
```

However, there is something strange going on here - in the induction proof, we are doing induction on l1 and not l2 - and from the proof, it looks like we are assuming l2 doesn't change in the induction case. But when we later apply it with `l2:=l1`, we are breaking this assumption.

Indeed, if we try to prove

```
Theorem app_length_cons'' : forall (X:Type) (l1:list X) (x:X),
                              length (l1 ++ x :: l1) = S (length (l1 ++ l1)).
```

use the same method

```
Proof.
  intros.
  induction l1 as [| h l1'].
  reflexivity.
  simpl.
  -- Can't rewrite use IHl1' : length (l1' ++ x :: l1') = S (length (l1' ++ l1')),
  -- since the goal is S (length (l1' ++ x :: h :: l1')) = S (S (length (l1' ++ h :: l1')))
```

it looks like the assumption that l2 doesn't change is broken thus the proof won't work.

I'm pretty sure I'm missing something here. Why can we substitute different identifiers with the same identifier?

Answer (score 7):

> it looks like we are assuming `l2` doesn't change in the induction case.
>   But when we later apply it with `l2:=l1`, we are breaking this
>   assumption.

No. If we regard `l1` to be a value which is repeatedly decreased in the induction proof, note that we let `l2` to be equal to the *initial* value of `l1` -- such value will not change in the induction steps. In other words: the value of `l1` will decrease, but `l2` will always be the *initial* value of `l1`.

We can even compare it with recursion in programming:

```
# pseudocode
def f(x, y):
   if x==0: return baseValue
   use f(x-1, y)
   return something
```

Just because `f(x, y)` is defined by induction on `x`, it does not mean that later on we can't call `f(a, a)` where both arguments have the same value `a`.

Comment: Ah I see what you mean - I **was** being exceptionally thick headed, that's for sure.

Answer (score 6):

(1)
We are just using this general theorem to prove a special case, we don't change anything here.
When we use this coq construction

```
apply app_length_cons' with (l1:=l1) (l2:=l1).
```

we just in some sense instantiate this **universally quantified** formula

$$
\forall l_1, l_2. \mid l_1 \cdot (x :: l_2) \mid~=~succ \mid l_1 \cdot l_2 \mid
$$

with $l_2 = l_1$:

$$
\forall l_1. \mid l_1 \cdot (x :: l_1) \mid~=~succ \mid l_1 \cdot l_1 \mid.
$$

(2)
As for your last proof, it's often harder to prove a special case than a more general one. When you do induction on $l_1$ you get the head $h$ of the list $l_1$ twice. You can easily get rid of the first occurrence of $h$, but the second one is buried deeply inside concatenation.

By the way, you can still do one rewrite if you generalize the induction hypothesis in the variable $x$, but this seems to lead nowhere:

```
Theorem app_length_cons'' : forall (X:Type) (x:X) (l1:list X),
                              length (l1 ++ x :: l1) = S (length (l1 ++ l1)).
Proof.
  intros.
  generalize dependent x.
  induction l1 as [| h l1']; intro.
  reflexivity.
  simpl.
  rewrite IHl1' with (x := h).
```